# Show that $-2, -1, 0, i$ lies in the Mandelbrot set but that $1$ lies outside of it

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, induction, complex-dynamics

**The Question**
Let $c$ be a complex number. The complex numbers $z_n(c)$ are defined recursively by

$z_1(c)=c$, $z_{n++1}(c)=(z_n(c))^2+c$ for $n\geq1$

The *Mandelbrot set* is defined by

$M=\{c\in\mathbb{C} |$ the sequence $(z_n(c))$ is bounded $\}$

Show that each of $-2, -1, 0, i$ lies in $M$ but that $1 \notin M$

For -2, -1, and 0 I just did some math and showed by example that they have an upper bound. 
I am stuck on how to prove that $i\in M$. I'd imagine that it's an induction, but not sure how to go about it.

Additionally, it's pretty obvious (if you go through it a bit) that for $c=1$ the set of recursive equations are unbounded. Could someone help me figure out how to to show this inductively?

Comment: To show that $c=-1\in M$, you probably computed some terms to get the sequence $(-1,0,-1,0,\ldots)$ - thus, the sequence is periodic.  Similarly for $c=-2$, you must've computed $(0,-2,2,2,\ldots)$ so that the sequence is *eventually* periodic. Something similar should happen with $c=i$, if you compute a few terms.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence for $i$ goes like 
$$i\mapsto -1+i\mapsto -i\mapsto -1+i\mapsto\ldots $$
so it is eventually periodic, hence bounded.
The sequence for $1$ starts
$$1\mapsto 2\mapsto 5\mapsto\ldots $$
so seems to diverge. Indeed, this follows from proposition 2 below.

**Proposition 1.** If $|c|>2$, then $c\notin M$.

*Proof.*
Now if $|c|>2$, then we show by induction that $|z_n(c)|$ is $\ge |c|$ and strictly increasing by a factor $>1$: 
$$|z_{n+1}(c)|\ge |z_n(c)|^2-|c|\ge (|z_n(c)|-1)|c|>|c|$$
as $|z_n(c)|\ge |c|>2$. And then 
$$|z_{n+1}(c)|\ge |z_n(c)|^2-|c|\ge |z_n(c)|\cdot|c|-|z_n(c)|=|z_n(c)|(|c|-1).$$
We conclude $|z_{n}(c)|\ge (|c|-1)^n$ for $n\ge 1$, so the sequence is unbounded. $_\square$

**Proposition 2.** If $|z_m(c)|>2$ for some $m$, then $c\notin M$.

*Proof.*
By proposition 1, we may assume $|c|\le 2$. 
$$ |z_{n+1}(c)|\ge |z_n(c)|^2-2$$
Now if $|z_n(c)|=2+h$, then $|z_{n+1}(c)|\ge 2+2h$. Thus from $n=m$ on, $|z_n(c)|-2$ grows exponentially. $_\square$

Comment: Yes, very subtle.